# How can one set minimalist interface of Excel with C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Using C#, I'm writing a program that has to use Excel only in order to edit some tabular data provided by my program. My program just creates an Excel application (the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` object), creates within it a workbook, creates a worksheet, puts the data in Excel, and, after this, allows to a user to edit these data. The edited data can be easily read by my program. That's, in principal, all what I need from Excel.

This, therefore, means that a user of my program should not be able to format data in Excel, save an Excel file to the hard drive, open Excel files, and so on and so on. A user even does not need the Excel ribbon. Working with formulas is also does not required. Hotkeys (like "Ctrl + B" making the font bold, "Ctrl + S" saving the file, and so on) should be also not workable.

**My question is**: Is there a way to simply set such a minimalist interface for Excel? Or I should disable any aspect mentioned above by hand, step by step (disable the ribbon, switch off the hotkeys ans so on)?

Comment: It sounds like you don't even need Excel. Why Excel and not just a data grid?

Comment: That's an interesting question! :) But, anyway, let's assume that I nevertheless need Excel!

Answer (score 0):

When working within a VSTO project, you can disable most/all of the UI by using a [custom ribbon XML file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx) (there is a visual designer too but I doubt it would be sufficient for this).

To remove things, add a section for what you're removing, and set visible="false" or enabled="false" (users could still potentially add it back to the ribbon, but disabling it makes it grayed out).

e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
 <commands>
  <command idMso="Cut" enabled="false" />
 </commands>
 <ribbon>
  <tabs>
   <tab idMso="TabHome" visible="false" />
  </tabs>
 </ribbon>
 <contextualTabs>
  <tabSet idMso="TabSetDrawingTools" visible="false" />
 </contextualTabs>
 <backstage>
  <tab idMso="TabInfo" visible="false">
 </backstage>
 <contextMenus>
  <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuText">
   <!-- you can't hide a context menu entirely, you have to hide each item -->
   <button idMso="FontDialog" visible="false" />
  </contextMenu>
 </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

This may also be possible if you're working with Office in the way that you seem to be, I don't really know.